# What is the pupose "@update:model-value " in vue and how it works?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I looked for a lot to find the example in order to understand  the following code but useless. If you can share the link where I can read about that or write the example with the parent and the child components. I will be grateful

```
<q-input
      :model-value="modelValue"
      @update:model-value=""
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Read this from the Vue [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model)

Its essentially what v-model does but sometime you might want to modify it for your own use case

Comment: I was confusing why we are still using update...., if instead we can use v-model. Or still there some privileges with update.. we can do, but not with v-model? I think you have already answered to my question

Answer (score 2):

In version `3.x`, `v-model` in a custom component is equivalent to passing a prop `modelValue` and emitting an event `update:modelValue`.

```
<ChildComponent v-model="pageTitle" />

<!-- would be a shortcut to -->

<ChildComponent
  :modelValue="pageTitle"
  @update:modelValue="pageTitle = $event"
/>
```

Comment: is there a way to name it with another name than modelValue ? For exemple if I want to pass multiple v-model to a component

Comment: @Nicolas I don’t think you can use another name but if you have multiple values. Then instead of a string you can pass as an object.

Comment: @Nicolas You can change to other name, [doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#multiple-v-model-bindings)

Comment: @foxiris The doc which you shared is showing how we can pass multiple v-model attributes to pass. In that they are not saying anything related to changing the v-model name.

Comment: I don't get it. In the doc `v-model:first-name="first"` which means you can change the name from `v-model:modelValue="first"` to `first-name`.